# Error on deploy a NodeJS app in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-deployment

I'm getting the error:

```
2012-01-28T00:13:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2012-01-28T00:13:51+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-28T00:13:51+00:00 app[web.1]: node.js:134
2012-01-28T00:13:51+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
2012-01-28T00:13:51+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2012-01-28T00:13:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:423:10)
2012-01-28T00:13:51+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'
2012-01-28T00:13:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:320:11)
2012-01-28T00:13:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._load (module.js:266:25)
2012-01-28T00:13:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

My Node app server is in server.js at the root, I have no idea how to fix this. 
I've done it from cloud9ide and it works fine, I did a deploy from there to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is trying to require('server') somewhere in your app, which isn't necessary.  The error is coming from module.js which deals with require-ing node modules.  If you could provide your Procfile and maybe some source code it might be easier to pin down the problem, but based on first glance it looks like there's a relative path pointing to /app/server.js somewhere in your server code which shouldn't be doing so.